# Pupateer page.evaluate randomly stopped work when parsing website

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium

i created a webparser for option alerts about 3 weeks ago and all was going well, as of today I checked on it and for some reason it was returning empty values, I thought maybe the website reformated but there is nothing different, i have been trying many fixes for the last hours so hoping I could get some help, below is the code I use for parising the website:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--single-process', 
        '--disable-gpu'],
        dumpio: true,
        headless: true
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(process.env.ALERTS_PARSER_WEBSITE);
      // page.on("console", msg => console.log("PAGE LOG:", msg));


      const data = await page.evaluate(() =>
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table > tbody > tr"), (row) =>
          Array.from(row.querySelectorAll("th, td"), (cell) => cell.innerText)
        )
      );
```

And then I map the data into my own array and pass back to my front-end, the website I am trying to parse from is [Bar Chart Unusual Options Activity](https://www.barchart.com/options/unusual-activity/stocks?orderBy=tradeTime&orderDir=desc). You can inspect the site there and see that the query selector should work, im really on my last leg on this one so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the cause may be, but I manage to get the data only with `puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });` and

```
page.setDefaultTimeout(300_000);
// ...
await page.waitForSelector("table > tbody > tr");
```

(the last may be needed only on slow machines like my one).

Maybe the site starts using some protection against headless mode.

P.S. When I try to get a page screenshot in headless mode, I instantly get this:

[image]

P.P.S. It seems the solution is simple for now. As `response.request().redirectChain()` is empty, the site only checks the user agent header in the first request. So this seems to fix the issue for the headless mode (the difference can be inferred from comparing `await browser.userAgent()` values in both mode):

```js
  await page.setUserAgent((await browser.userAgent()).replace('HeadlessChrome', 'Chrome'));

  await page.goto('https://www.barchart.com/options/unusual-activity/stocks?orderBy=tradeTime&orderDir=desc');
```

Comment: You my friend are a life saver, how did you manag to think of this conclusion? What was the process you went through? I was trying to figure it out forever?

Comment: It is a bit of experience) The difference between healful and headless behavior is a frequent cause of issues. The process is all in the answer: try healful mode; if it is OK — try screenshot of a headless page; if the page is an instant error and there are no redirections (i.e. no complicated intermediate browser mode checks), then the user agent header is the main suspect)